# $f(x)$ is a degree five polynomial; it's given that $f(x) +1$ is divisible by $(x-1)^3$ $f(x)-1$ is divisible by $(x+1)^3$. Find $f(x)$

Tags: polynomials

Let $f(x)$ a five degree polynomial. We are given that $f(x)+1$ is divisible by $(x-1)^3$ and that $f(x)-1$ is divisible by $(x+1)^3$. Find $f(x)$.

Comment: For a start we know $f(x)+1 = q(x)\cdot (x-1)^3$ for some polynomial $q(x)$

Answer (score 5):

Expliciting your hypothesis, there is $a,b,c$ such that $$f(x)+1 = (x-1)^3(ax^2+bx+c),$$ and $d,e,f$ such that $$f(x)-1=(x+1)^3(dx^2+ex+f).$$ Substrack these equations and you will have $$2 = (x-1)^3(ax^2+bx+c)-(x+1)^3(dx^2+ex+f).$$ I let you finish this exercice by equaling the coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Polynomials $g\left(x\right)=ax^{2}+bx+c$ and $h\left(x\right)=px^{2}+qx+r$
must exist with $a,p\neq0$ and:

$$f\left(x\right)=g\left(x\right)\left(x-1\right)^{3}-1=h\left(x\right)\left(x+1\right)^{2}+1$$